# Restrict incoming call iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

I want to create an iPhone app that would restrict incoming calls and SMS from a given phone number.

The phone would not ring or light up the screen. It simply would not do
anything when a call was received from that number. Also, in the recent call list, the number should not show up. When user opens my app, it would show the black list numbers.

Is this possible to develop, and will Apple approve this?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve such a drastic downvote. It is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't interfere with calls or SMSes in any way.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to do this and still be accepted in the App Store. No API provided by Apple can do anything like this. I don't know what more I can say to answer this.

Maybe [Core Telephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) would help you take a different approach. Even some things that you can do with that could prevent your app from being accepted into the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think it's even possible to intercept an incoming call. All processes have a priority assigned to them, and phone calls are one of the highest (more so than standard apps), so an app can't interrupt a higher priority process.

Secondly, it's not possible for an app was able to intercept an incoming call (or SMS), as that's a major security flaw. Your app can only access the contents of its sandbox (and some shared directories, such as photos).